# Byobu shows weird rectangle when trying to move left or right in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, byobu

When I try to move left or right in bash while byobu is enabled it doesn't do that but instead it just shows a little rectangle in the middle and the screen resolution in the top right corner. I can only move left and right while pressing the shift or ctrl key additionally.

I already uninstalled byobu with `sudo apt purge byobu`, removed every config file of byobu I could find and then reinstalled it, but still same annoying box appearing.

I really don't want to have to always hold down the shift key when moving left or right, is there any solution to this?

Additional information:

- The server is running Ubuntu Server 17.04
- this suddenly started happening out of nowhere
- I've shut down my server multiple times
- I'm using putty to connect to my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was Putty's fault.
I just had to remove it, clear its registry entries and then reinstall it and now everything works again!